# « Seul » et « seulement » : quelle est la différence ?

Tags: grammaire, sens, adjectifs, adverbes

J'ai vu une phrase qui commence par « Seul l'héritier de Serpentard aurait le pouvoir d'ouvrir la Chambre… »

J'aurais pensé qu'on devrait l'écrire « **Seulement** l'héritier de Serpentard aurait le pouvoir d'ouvrir la Chambre… ».

J'ai tort ?

Comment: Il faudrait vraiment le reste de la phrase. En [canardant](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Seul%20l'héritier%20de%20Serpentard%20puisse%20region%3Afr) l’extrait, je tombe sur une phrase qui se balade sur divers Wiki. Mais « Seul l’héritier » est dans ce cas dans une relative, ce qui donne tout son sens au subjonctif (sinon, on emploierait « Seul l’héritier peut »). Est-ce de cette phrase dont tu parles ?

Comment: @Aerovistae: Good question, but I think “commence avec” would be the right way to frame it.HTH. Wrt to seule vs seulement, there may be better answers out there but I think “seul” is an adjective while seulement is an adverb

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Seul* peut être **adjectif** :

- Avec le sens d'« isolé », « solitaire » :

  > J'aime à marcher seule dans la ville.
- Avec le sens d'« unique » :

  > Pas un seul petit morceau
  >   De mouche ou de vermisseau

  (Jean de La Fontaine - *La Cigale et la Fourmi*)

Il peut aussi être **adverbe** (ou « adjectif à valeur adverbiale »), avec le sens de « uniquement », « exclusivement ». Dans ce cas il est placé avant le nom et, contrairement à la règle générale des adverbes, il s'accorde avec celui-ci.

**Références** :

- [La banque de dépannage linguistique](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1615) :

  > Par ailleurs, l’adjectif seul est aussi parfois employé avec une
  >   valeur adverbiale. Dans ce cas, il a toujours une valeur restrictive
  >   comme seulement. Il signifie « sans rien, sans personne de plus ». À
  >   première vue, logiquement, l’invariabilité de seul dans ce contexte
  >   devrait s’imposer. Mais la tradition grammaticale dicte pourtant son
  >   accord et l’usage est bien fixé. Ainsi, le mot seul employé comme
  >   adverbe recevra les marques de genre et de nombre du nom sur lequel il
  >   fait porter une restriction.
- [*Grammaire méthodique du français*](http://fr.scribd.com/doc/54283670/135/LES-CLASSES-MORPHOLOGIQUS-DE-PREPOSITIONS) ( Riegel, Pellat & Rioul) (2009) p.655

  > Chapitre XIII – L’ADVERBE
  >
  > 4. La Morphologie des adverbes
  >
  > 4.1. Formes et formations de l’adverbe
  >
  > L’adverbe est invariable, à l’exception de :
  >
  > - tout qui, lorsqu’il marque l’intensité, s’accorde avec les adjectifs féminins à initiale consonantique (ou h aspiré) qu’il
  >     modifie : Ils sont tout ridés / Elles sont toutes ridées, la seconde
  >     phrase étant ambiguë entre une lecture adverbiale [= tout à fait] et
  >     pronominale [=chacune] de la forme toutes ;
  > - l’adjectif à valeur adverbiale seul(e), antéposée au sujet comme marqueur argumentatif d’exclusivité : Seule cette femme est allée au
  >     Tibet (= Il n’y a que cette femme qui…)
- *Le bon usage* (Maurice Grevisse)  (édition 2007)

  > Parmi les épithètes détachés en début de phrase, il faut mettre SEUL à part : cet adjectif occupe, en effet, très fréquemment cette position et souvent même sans pause, quand, se rapportant au sujet et s'accordant avec celui-ci, il a une valeur quasi adverbiale et pourrait être remplacé par "seulement"; il marque que l'idée s'applique exclusivement au mot auquel il se rapporte.
  >
  > *Seule une femme pourrait le consoler*.

Quelle différence entre « seul » à valeur adverbiale et « seulement » ?

Comme le fait remarquer Grevisse, *seul* à valeur adverbiale se trouve fréquemment en début de phrase et cela permet de lever toute ambiguïté de sens.

*Seulement* en début de phrase ou introduisant une proposition peut selon le contexte avoir le sens de « toutefois », « cependant ». « *Seulement l'héritier de Serpentard aurait le pouvoir d'ouvrir la Chambre…* » peut se comprendre comme « Toutefois l'héritier de Serpentard aurait le pouvoir d'ouvrir… » ou « Uniquement l'héritier de Serpentard aurait le pouvoir d'ouvrir… ».

En employant « seul » on n'a plus d'hésitation sur le sens.

Comment: Je remplacerais « unique » par « le moindre ». À part ça, excellente réponse avec références et explication de l'influence qu'a la position de ces mots.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: Et bien, j'ai hésité, je voulais montrer comment on peut passer de "seul" adj. à seul adv, via le sens de "seul" -> "unique". En fait, l'idéal serait de trouver un autre exemple.. . Je ne sais pas si j'ai été claire ?

Comment: Reponse bien explique.  J'ajouterais ceci, qui me semble fait une difference adjacente : On peut dire "Seulement 3 des pommes sont bonnes."  On ne peut pas dire "Seul 3 des pommes sont bonnes."  "Seul" au debut de la phrase a vraiment un sens d'"uniquement".

Answer (score 5):

Seul est un adjectif, seulement est un adverbe (comme beaucoup de mots en 'ment'. L'adjectif est lié à un nom (**Seul l'héritier** peut...), l'adverbe à une action (l'héritier **peut seulement**...).

Comment: Contre exemple trouvé chez Balzac, même construction de phrase (Adv - S - V) que l'exemple donné par le PO avec "seulement" (et pas "seul") avant le nom sujet : *Seulement le feu bruissait, comme pour faire comprendre la profondeur du silence.* — (Honoré de Balzac, La Femme de trente ans, 1832)

Comment: @Laure L'usage cité est littéraire, et je ne l'ai jamais entendu à l'oral en 37 ans. Peut-on considérer que c'est un cas hyper spécifique et que la règle citée par NathanZ est correcte ? C'est mon avis. Pour une analyse plus complète, voir la réponse de ... eh ben la tienne en fait. ;-)

Comment: C'est vrai que seulement s'utilise aussi comme un substitut de "mais". La phrase de Balzac entre dans cette catégorie à mon avis

Comment: @NathanZ: Non, il suffit de ressortir le texte et il est clair que Balzac veut dire ici qu'"il n'y avait que le feu qui bruissait..." et pas "mais". Dire que dans le cas de "seulement" que l'adverbe est lié uniquement à une action est inexact. Et si tu parlais de façon plus générale sur les adverbes, les adverbes modifient aussi des adjectifs.

Comment: @RomainVALERI: La citation que j'ai choisi est littéraire mais l'usage de "seulement" pour signifier "uniquement" est possible et s'entend. Le seul fat que ce soit possible grammaticalement empêche de dire que "seulement ne peut porter que sur l'action".  Dans cette phrase de Balzac "seulement" est bien employé pour dire que le seul bruit qu'on entendait était le feu qui bruissait.

Answer (score 2):

Well, basically, "seul" means alone or lonely depending on the context and "seulement" means only. That's all there is to it.

"Seul l'héritier de Serpentard aurait le pouvoir d'ouvrir la Chambre…" Is saying "The heir of Slytherin alone would have the power of opening the Chamber"

"Seulement l'héritier de Serpentard aurait le pouvoir d'ouvrir la Chambre" Is saying "Only the heir of Slytherin would have the power of opening the Chamber"

Both are grammatically correct, although the use of the former is much more common in French.

(Props for reading Harry Potter)

Comment: "Seulement l'héritier de Serpentard aurait le pouvoir d'ouvrir la Chambre"  could also mean *The heir of Slytherin  would have the power to open the Chamber though*. Both are grammatically correct but "seulement" can be ambiguous when at the beginning of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Dans cette construction (et quelques autres proches), *seul* est effectivement un synonyme de *seulement* (il reste un adjectif et s'accorde donc). Voir [TLFi](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/seul) au point I.C. (si je ne me trompe pas, la numérotation du TLFi est un peu confuse).

Answer (score 0):

Les messages linguistiques véhiculent de l’information et cette information peut être explicite ou implicite selon la volonté du locuteur et selon les centres d’intérêt qu'il veut activer chez le destinataire du message.

En ce qui concerne "seul" et "seulement", il faut reconnaitre que ces deux mots ont des sens adjacents et c'est un peu délicat : les deux mots renvoient vers le sens de l'unicité ou de la restriction mais avec des nuances subtiles.

Pour lever l’ambiguïté je vais procéder de manière à essayer d'envisager les cas d'usage possibles, en proposant pour chaque cas une question qui pourrait avoir comme réponse une phrase mentionnant cet usage.

Voici quelques cas d'usage:

- Exemple 1

  > **Seule** la clef magique peut ouvrir cette porte.

  cette affirmation pourrait être la réponse à la question :

  > avec quelle clef peut-on ouvrir cette porte?

  Pour dire : il faut une clef x et pas d'autres clefs, dans le sens de "une clef **à l'exclusion de toute autre**". Ce sens correspond à "only" en anglais.

  il y a une **focalisation** sur "clef".
- Exemple 2

  > **Le seul** mammifère à pondre des œufs est l’ornithorynque.

  La question qu'on aurait pu poser est :

  > Quels sont les mammifères qui pondent des œufs ?

  *Le seul* est une locution pronominale et elle est ici utilisée pour exprimer l'unicité : on s'attendait à ce qu'il y ait beaucoup de mammifères qui pondent des œufs alors que la phrase affirme qu'il y a une espèce unique qui pond.

  Dans ce cas *seul* peut être formalisé par "**il existe une entité x, et une unique entité, telle que...**" (x peut être une personne, un objet…). En outre, le sens du mot "seul" ne se limite pas à ça, il peut être aussi employé pour indiquer qu'une personne n'est pas assistée ou accompagnée par quelqu'un d'autre.
- Exemple 3

  > *J’étais **seul** à la maison*.
- Exemple 4

  > *L'écolier est allé **seul** à l’école.*

  Cette affirmation pourrait être la réponse à la question :

  > Comment l'écolier est-il allé à l'école ?

  Avec pour sens implicite : l'écolier est allé à l'école sans ses parents  ; ce sens correspond à "lonely" (voire "alone") en anglais.

Mais alors, "seulement" n'est-il pas "seul"+e+"ment", la forme adverbiale de "seul", cela ne peut-il exprimer un sens qui en découle ? Pas tout à fait !

Pour attaquer le problème on va remplacer "seul" par "seulement" et voir ce que ça donne:

- Exemple 5

  > *L’écolier est allé à l’école **seulement**.*

  Cette affirmation pourrait être la réponse à la question:

  > Vers quelles destinations l’écolier est-il allé ?

  Sens implicite : l’écolier aurait pu visiter d'autres lieux que l’école mais il ne l'a pas fait (restriction des localités). Il y a mise en relief d'une restriction, avec une nuance de "quelque chose de manqué". C'est à dire qu'on s'attendait à un scenario alors qu'un autre scenario s'est installé. Juxtaposition de présupposé/supposé : ici on est clairement face à un cas d'**adverbe paradigmatisant** selon le classement de "Henning Nølke"...
- Exemple 6

  > *Il y'a **seulement** le désert là-bas !*

  la question qui peut être posée est:

  > Qu'y a-t-il là-bas?

  Sens implicite : "on s'attendait à trouver beaucoup de choses mais on n'a rien trouvé d'autre que le désert.  Bien qu'il s'agit de peu de mots, on sent une sorte d'expression d'amertume et de désillusion qui émane de cette phrase: le locuteur est loin d'être neutre !
- Exemple 7

  > *Il y a **seulement** un an...*

  La question qui peut être posée est:

  > depuis quand ?

  Cela exprime "une période passée **qui ne dépasse pas** un an" alors qu'on s'attendait à une période plus longue.
- Exemple 8

  > Ils auront pu gagner la guerre **seulement** ils ont dû faire face à la fatalité du destin.

  Ici, "seulement" est un connecteur oppositif interchangeable avec "mais".
- Exemple 9

  > Si seulement tu m'avais dit la vérité.

  [c'est le titre d'une chanson de Richard Antony]

  ("if only you had told me the truth")

  Ici "*seulement*" exprime un cas, un contexte ou une condition qui est requise mais qui n'a pas été remplie. Encore une fois l’énonciateur exprime une  divergence entre ce qu'il attendait et ce qui est arrivé.

Henning Nølke s'est intéressé à l'emploi des adverbes en français et a étudié ce genre de cas  en insistant sur la dimension implicite — mais présente — du point de vue du locuteur dans *Le regard du locuteur* (avec ses deux éditions). Pour plus d’informations, consultez [cet article](https://tidsskrift.dk/index.php/revue_romane/article/view/11842/22524).

Answer (score -1):

La phrase interprétée avec *seulement*, ne reprend pas le verbe.

- Avec *seul* : il est question de capacité personnelle, de personne physique apte à entrer en action, ou à réaliser une tâche.
- Avec *seulement* : il est question de droit, de personne morale autorisée à agir ou faire réaliser.

D'un coté l'adjectif renvoie à la réalité d'une personne, de l'autre l'adverbe renvoie à la réalisation de l'action par une personne.

Comment: Non, il n'y a pas du tout cette nuance entre *seul* et *seulement*.

Comment: @Gilles En êtes-vous si certain ? Un comédien ne prononcera pas du tout de la même façon les deux mots, non seulement parce qu'ils n'ont pas la même prosodie, mais parce que l'intention du metteur en scène peut orienter l'interprétation de la scène en changeant l'origine de l'action (subjective avec seul, objective sinon). En effet, littéralement les deux termes sont interchangeables, l'écrit laisse une ambiguïté sur l'interprétation du lecteur, mais oralement vous ferez un choix, consciemment ou non.

Comment: @cl-r « Seul un médecin est autorisé … », « le propriétaire est seul habilité … », … Je n'utiliserais pas *seulement* dans ce sens, en fait.

Comment: @gilles Un gynécologue est un spécialiste. Seulement un gynécologue peut recoudre une plaie superficielle s'il est le seul thérapeute sur zone. *Seulement* synonyme *cependant, mais, toutefois*. Moins-moinsoyerez-vous si vous êtes concerné?

Comment: What is "moin-moinsoyerez"? Couldn't find any references to such a verb.

Comment: @Aerovistae C'est une 'francophonisation' putative en cours d'inscription au dictionnaire arachnophile des néologismes, ou encore,  essai pour traduire 'down' dans le cas d'un vote négatif réservé à l'usage du Web. Bref, une demande de motivation aux internautes qui on cliqué sur la flèche qui pointe vers le bas.

Comment: @Aerovistae et comme moins par moins égal plus, moins-moinsêtre annule ce vote négatif (sans toutefois envisager qu'il devienne positif). Tout cela n'est pas très académique, sauf peut-être pour l'Oulipo